# what are the caveats of sending email via the "mail" command?

Tags: email

I want to send emails from my work computers so that I can notify myself when various long-running tasks are completed. As I understand it, the command below looks up bar.com's MX record, makes a connection to the mail server and does SMTP to send the message:

```
echo “Hello world” | mail -s “Hello world” foo@bar.com
```

What do I need to know so that I can avoid being flagged/blocked as a spammer?

Comment: Not sending spam in first place.

Comment: Why do you expect sending using `mail` to be different than sending with anything else? (And what does this have to do with Unix or Linux?)

Comment: I think `mail` relies on some other software in order to send beyond the box, so don't assume this will work at all until you try it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it has nothing to do with anything Linux/Unix specific

Comment: @Anthon: Ok, I flagged to have it deleted, sorry for asking.

Comment: @Mat, Anthon: The question is about a `mail` command running on a Linux system, which is on-topic. However, it lacks motivation: why should mail sent with `mail` risk being flagged as spam more than mail sent with other programs?

Comment: This seems fine to me

Comment: @Gilles, I think the real issue is that the MTA at many work places may be configured to drop or block such emails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference between sending mail via the [mail command](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_Mail.htm) or via any other program. As such a mail send via *mail (1)* is not more nor less likely to be identified as spam.

( I would add that this is the default way in which many non-cron tasks send you their mail, but I have no evidence to back that up. )

As to avoid having your mail seen as spam: Make sure that your mail does not look like spam.
E.g. not just a single HTML link, not just a picture. No l33t spelling. Valid origins. Etc etc. Non of these are specific to the mail command.